# The system $y(n) = c\cdot x(n) +d$ is given. Is the system linear, time-invariant, stable and causal?

Tags: signal-processing

> The system $y(n) = c\cdot x(n) +d $ is given. (Unfortunately, nothing more is given.) Is the system linear, time-invariant, stable and/or causal?

I assumed, that $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$

### Linearity

We need to show, that $T\{k_1x_1(n)+k_2x_2(n)\}=k_1\cdot T(x_1(n)\}+k_2\cdot T\{x_2(n)\}$ (I assume for $k_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and T might be the shift-function)

$T\{cx(n)+d\}=T\{cx(n)\}+T\{d\}=c\cdot T\{x(n)\}+d$

### Time-invariant

We need to show, that $T\{x(n)\}=y(n)\implies T\{x(n-n_0)\}=y(n-n_0)$

$T\{c\cdot x(n-n_0)+d\}=c\cdot T\{x(n-n_0)\}+d=c\cdot T\{x(n)-x(n_0)\}+d=T\{c\cdot (x(n)-x(n_0))+d\}=T\{c\cdot x(n)-c(n_0)+d\}=y(n)-y(n_0)=y(n-n_0)$

### Stability

We need to show, that $\mid y(n)\mid <N<\infty \text{ with } \mid x(n)\mid < M,\; \text{  I assume for some fixed } M,N\in \mathbb{R}$

$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mid T\{cx(n)+d\}\mid<N<\infty=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mid c\cdot T\{x(n)\}+d\mid<N<\infty=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mid T\{x(n)\}\mid<N<\infty=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} M<N<\infty\implies M<N<\infty$

### Causality

We need to show, that $x(n) = 0$ for $n<n_0 \implies y(n) = 0$ for $n<n_0$

$y(n) = cx(n)+d=c\cdot 0 +d = d \implies y(n) = d$ The system is causal for $d=0$

---

Is this ok or complete nonsense? Furthermore, I apologize for wrong/non-complete definitions.

Comment: You get stability for free. It's not a dynamic system, so any bounded x(n) will always yield a bounded y(n).  It is nonlinear if d is nonzero since you lose homogeneity. It is time invariant if c, d are constants.  It is casual since the current output does not depend on any future inputs or outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you may be over thinking it, in that there are simpler proofs.

**Linear**: Not unless $d=0$.  Let $x[n] = x_1[n]+x_2[n]$.  Then:

$$y[n] = cx[n] + d = cx_1[n] + cx_2[n] + d$$

But now let $y_1[n] = cx_1[n] + d$ and $y_2[n] = cx_2[n] + d$.  Then $y_1 + y_2 = cx_1 + cx_2 + 2d$, so if $d \ne 0$ this is nonlinear.

**Time invariant**: Yes as long as $c,d$ are constant.  Let $n = n_0 + K$.  Then $y[n_0 + K] = cx[n_0 + K] + d$

**Stable**: The coarsest stability criterion we have is BIBO.  Presuming again that $c,d$ are constant, then let $x$ be bounded such that $|x[n]| \le X \forall n$.  Then $y[n] \le  c|X| + d \lt \infty$

**Causal**: by definition of causality, the output can depend only on current and previous inputs.  It does, in that $y[n] = y(x[n])$.

Comment: Do you mean $y_1(n) + y_2(n) = cx_1(n) + cx_2(n) + 2d$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I got lazy with my brackets